# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present - Error - Optional.get in JUNIT Testing with Spring

Tags: java, junit

I have a test where an Optional was used. In the method, its stating no value was present.  Here is the code, I have. How can I make this pass without NoSuchElementException.

```
 public jobs theID(Integer id) {  
        if( id == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Its missing.");
        }


        return jobTitleMapper.entityToModel(this.jobTitleRepository.findById(id).get());
}
```

It is fussing about the get() from Java 8.

How do I use an Optional with isPresent correctly in this sense?

The test is:

```
public void findIdTest() {
    Jobs jt = this.Service.theID(Entities.thisID);
    Assert.assertNotNull(jt);
    Assert.assertEquals(Entities.thisID, .getId());
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `jOptional<JobTitleEntity> jTOptional = jTOptional.findById(id);` it does not make sense to me, also you didn't use it after.

Comment: Sorry, that should not have been there. It was older code. Deleted it.

Answer (score 6):

That happens because the Optional returned by:
`this.jobTitleRepository.findById(id)` can return an `empty`, so if you call get() on it it will throw a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

You can fix that with something like:
`this.jobTitleRepository.findById(id).orElseGet(null)`
or
`this.jobTitleRepository.findById(id).orElseGet(new Jobs())`

or fix the return Optional type in the original method: `jobTitleRepository.findById(id)`

Can you post this method `jobTitleRepository.findById(id)` on your post aswell?

Comment: this.jobTitleRepository.findById(id).orElseGet(null) is not working. Use this.jobTitleRepository.findById(id).orElse(null) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Must check Option  `YourObject.findById(id).isPresent()`

exemple:

```
 public  YourObject getYourObject(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return objectRepository.findById(id).isPresent() ? 
        objectRepository.findById(id).get(): null;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are discouraged because it is often difficult to see the specific change or answer that you have made that solves the problem. A bit of explanation will make your answer much easier and faster for users.

Answer (score 0):

`jobTitleRepository.findById(id)` it always returns an optional class so you don't need check if it is null, also before you call `assertEquals()` you can check if object with passed id exists by calling `someOptional.isPresent()` and if it's true you can make assert. But you should project your test cases to avoid mixing codintional statmens with asserations.