# Error when tring to fetch data from MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, runtime-error

I am currently trying to fetch data from monogDb and then using this data to performe aggregation queries. I am not sure I have done this correctly but this is the code so far. But when I press the buttom it crashed the app and the following error happens as seen below. Any idea as to why/ any solutions? Appreciate the help!

ERROR:

```
2023-12-17 17:10:57.338  1082-1715  OneSearchS...stProvider com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  Failed to fetch suggestions from AppSearch, fallback to AGA
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:684)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:486)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2138)
at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:59)
at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.lambda$onResult$0(SearchSessionUtil.java:129)
atandroid.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.$r8$lambda$_nlk9WiPjSfaAsqKYmp0aPvSRC0(SearchSessionUtil.java:1)
atandroid.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:13) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:144)
at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:16)
at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.lambda$onResult$0(SearchSessionUtil.java:129) 
at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.$r8$lambda$_nlk9WiPjSfaAsqKYmp0aPvSRC0(SearchSessionUtil.java:1) 
at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:13) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

GetMongoClient:

```
@SuppressLint("AuthLeak")
fun getMongoClient(): MongoClient {
    return MongoClients.create("My String goes here -> taken from mongodb")
}
```

FetchDataFromMongoDb:

```
fun fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection: MongoCollection<Document>): List<Document> {
    // Define your aggregation pipeline stages here
    val pipeline = listOf(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("age", "20")),
        // Add more pipeline stages as needed
    )

    // Execute the aggregation pipeline
    val result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)


    // Convert the result to a list of documents
    val documents = mutableListOf<Document>()

    try {
        // Code that might be causing the exception
        result.forEach { document ->
            documents.add(document)
            println("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")

        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }


    return documents
}
```

MainMongoDb:

```
@Composable
fun MainMongoData() {
    var fetchedData by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column {
        // Display your fetched data in a TextField
        TextField(
            value = fetchedData,
            onValueChange = { /* No-op for read-only TextField */ },
            label = { Text("Fetched Data") },
            readOnly = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )

        // Button to trigger search
        Button(onClick = {
            val client = getMongoClient()
            val database = client.getDatabase("people")
            val collection = database.getCollection("person")

            val documents = fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection)

            // Concatenate document JSON strings and update the TextField
            fetchedData = documents.joinToString("\n") { it.toJson() }

            client.close()
        }) {
            Text("Search")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No documents are found, but you're trying to access the results.  I'm not familiar with kotlin, but you may be trying to access the value of an Optional that has no value.  See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56256071/1686575

Comment: hmm maybe but not sure what I need to change in my code to achieve that using kotlin though. Will give it a try and see if I can figure it out, thanks!@JohnManko

Comment: This forEach looks suspicious. Judging from the documentation you should use collect instead. What's the exact type of this MongoCollection you are passing to your fetch function ?

Comment: From my IDE when reproducing a simple instance of your use case: 

Flow extension to iterate over elements is collect. Foreach wasn't introduced deliberately to avoid confusion. Flow is not a collection, iteration over it may be not idempotent and can launch computations with side-effects. This behaviour is not reflected in forEach name.

Answer (score 0):

`Kotlin` optional values are represented by `nullable` types, which can be either `null or non-nul`l. To access the value of a `nullable` type, you can use the `safe call operator` (?.), the `elvis operator` (?:), or the `not-null assertion operator (!!)`. You can also use the [methods](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm.optionals/java.util.-optional/) `getOrNull(), getOrElse(), or getOrDefault()` to map an `Optional<T>` to a `nullable type34.`

Sounds like you are trying to access the value of an Optional that has no value in the fetch function causing a `NoSuchElementException` to be thrown. To avoid this, you can use one of the methods mentioned above to handle the null case gracefully aka `getOrNull()` to `return null` if the Optional is empty, and then check for null before using the value:

```
val result = collection.find().first().getOrNull() if (result != null) { // do something with result } else { // handle null case }
```

Another possible issue - your use of  `forEach()` to iterate over the elements of a flow collection. [To iterate over the elements of a flow, use the `collect()` method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-stream-foreach), which takes a `suspending lambda` as an action. [`forEach()` is not available for flows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html), because it implies a synchronous and idempotent operation, which is not the case for flows256. Read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-stream-foreach) as well